# VS Code Angular template variables definition auto rename and navigation

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

Consider following snippet from controller:

```
  /* Local copies of Enumerators to use on template */
  MeasurementOriginEnum: typeof MeasurementOriginEnum = MeasurementOriginEnum;
```

And some usage in template:

```
<button *ngIf="element.getMeasurementStatus().id !== MeasurementOriginEnum.FROM_FILE" mat-menu-item (click)="deleteElement(element)">
```

As you can see, template uses literal name of controller variable (`MeasurementOriginEnum`).

Now the question: I think I installed countless VS Code extensions to support my development for Angular and I'm still lacking two following feature:

### Feature one: rename definitions on template

1. Right click on variable name in controlle `.ts` file
2. Select 'Rename symbol'
3. Enter new name
4. New name will be progresses to template as well

For my case, only `.ts` file gets updates, while template variable is not touched and I'm ending with names conflict

### Feature two: ctrl-click go to definition from template

1. On template ctrl-click on variable name
2. You shall be transfered to controller `ts` file variable definition

For my case nothing really happens...

I have Angular Essentials by John Papa installed, which ships with Angular Language Service, and according to it's description it shall provide those features...

Below is my full extensions list, maybe there is some kind of conflict?

```
Angular.ng-template
bradgashler.htmltagwrap
christian-kohler.path-intellisense
dbaikov.vscode-angular2-component-generator
EditorConfig.EditorConfig
eg2.tslint
eg2.vscode-npm-script
esbenp.prettier-vscode
infinity1207.angular2-switcher
johnpapa.angular-essentials
johnpapa.Angular2
johnpapa.winteriscoming
Mikael.Angular-BeastCode
ms-python.python
msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome
natewallace.angular2-inline
patrys.vscode-code-outline
PKief.material-icon-theme
robertohuertasm.vscode-icons
robinbentley.sass-indented
sanderledegen.angular-follow-selector
SonarSource.sonarlint-vscode
wayou.vscode-todo-highlight
```

Answer (score 1):

Question was asked a while ago. However, for feature one (rename definitions on template) I haven't found anything till now - maybe this is a unique selling point of WebStorm (from JetBrains). This seems to be a corresponding [feature request](https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service/issues/252)

For feature two (ctrl-click go to definition from template) I'm currently using [angular2-switcher by infinity1207](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=infinity1207.angular2-switcher).